# Setting a variable to a value produces Runtime Error 1004 : Application Defined or Object Defined Error

Tags: excel, vba

I am trying to get an array of values inside **column A of Sheet 'Codes'** and then get an array of all Sheets whose name starts with **'Price_Plan'***

My Start_Click Button is in a Sheet Named 'Macro' and I am trying to get data from column 'A' of Sheet named 'Codes'.

```
Private Sub Start_Click_Click()

    Dim wS As Worksheet, LastRow As Long
    Dim codeArray As Variant
    Dim lastCell As String
    Dim curSheet As Worksheet
    Dim ArraySheets() As String
    Dim x As Variant

    Set wS = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Codes")

    'Here we look in Column A
    LastRow = wS.Cells(wS.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
    lastCell = "A" & Str(LastRow)

    'Here we create array of our row values
    ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Codes").Activate
    Set codeArray = ActiveSheet.range("A2:" & lastCell).Value

    'Getting Array of Price Plan Sheets
    For Each curSheet In ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets
        If curSheet.Name Like "Price_Plan*" Then
            ReDim Preserve ArraySheets(x)
            ArraySheets(x) = curSheet.Name
            x = x + 1
        End If
    Next curSheet

End Sub
```

I get this Runtime Error at:

```
Set codeArray = ActiveSheet.range("A2:" & lastCell).Value
```

Comment: Remove the word `Set` - `.Value` does not return an `Object`, it returns a 2 dimensional array of `Value`

Comment: `Str` prepends a space to positive values, so you end up with e.g. `A 5` instead of `A5`. Just use `"A2:A" & LastRow`.

Comment: Thanks @braX  made the suggested changes and code seems to be working now

Comment: I assume you also made the change @GSerg suggested, as he is also correct.

Comment: @braX yes done those changes. Cheers!